Studying a non-abelian group of order 16 with two cyclic subgroups of order 8
$\newcommand{\Aut}{\mathrm{Aut}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$
I'm working on the following problem: Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order 16 with two distinct cyclic subgroups $A$ and $B$ of order $8$. Let $a$ and $b$ be generators of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Show that $bab^{-1}=a^5$.
I would appreciate any hints or suggestions, whether or not they follow the ideas I've written below.
My work so far: Since $G$ acts on $A$ by conjugation, we have a homomorphism $\phi:G\to\Aut(A)\cong (\Z/2)^2$. Thus any element of $G$—including $b$ in particular—acts by an involution on $A$, so $b^2$ must act trivially. Meanwhile $b$ itself cannot act trivially, since otherwise $bab^{-1}=a$, i.e., $ba=ab$, which would make $G$ abelian. Thus $\ker\phi$ cannot contain $b$. But it must contain $A$, so in fact $\ker\phi = A$, from which it follows that $b^2\in A$. Hence $A\cap B=\ang{a^2}=\ang{b^2}$ is cyclic of order 4, and $a^4=b^4$.
Since $A$ is index 2, it is normal, and it contains $\ang{a^4}$ as a characteristic subgroup. Hence $\ang{a^4}$ is normal in $G$. I would like to argue that $G/\ang{a^4}$ is abelian. (From here, it would follow that $[G,G]=\ang{a^4}$, so $bab^{-1}a^{-1} = a^4$ since it's not $1$, i.e., $bab^{-1}=a^5$.)
I know $G/\ang{a^4}$ certainly can't be $D_4$ since the quotient has (at least) two cyclic subgroups of order $4$ whereas $D_4$ has only one. But I can't see why the quotient can't be $Q_8$. This would require there to be another cyclic subgroup $C$ of order $8$ in $G$ with a generator $c$ satisfying $ab=c$ (so that $a,b,c$ play the roles of $i,j,k$ in the quotient), but I am struggling to find a way to see that this is not possible. Why can't there be a non-abelian group of order 16 with three distinct cyclic subgroups of order 8?

It's SmallGroup(16,6).

https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/M4(2).html

I did see that on that website, but I'm not sure how I can actually prove that that group is the unique nonabelian group of order 16 with two distinct cyclic subgroups of order 8 (besides just looking over the list and observing that it's true).

Write $bab^{-1} = a^k$, wlog $0 < k < 8$ with $k$ odd.
We have $A \trianglelefteq G$ of index $2$, so $b^2 \in A$.
Since $b^2$ has order $4$, we have $b^2 \in \{a^2,a^6\}$.
Suppose $b^2 = a^2$. Then $b$ centralizes $a^2$, so $a^2 = ba^2b^{-1} = a^{2k}$. This implies $2k \equiv 2 \mod{8}$, so $k \equiv 1 \mod{4}$. Hence $k \in \{1,5\}$. Since $G$ is nonabelian we cannot have $k = 1$, so $k = 5$.
In the case $b^2 = a^6$, argue similarly to find that $k = 5$.
Hence we conclude that $bab^{-1} = a^5$.

Edit: At the end you ask why there couldn't be three cyclic subgroups of order $8$. Well, suppose $a$, $b$, $c$ generate distinct cyclic subgroups of order $8$.
Then $bab^{-1} = a^5$, $bcb^{-1} = c^5$, $aca^{-1} = c^5$. Moreover as you already know, we must have $a^4 = b^4 = c^4$.
So $G/\langle a^4 \rangle$ is abelian of order $8$ with three distinct cyclic subgroups of order $4$. By looking at the possible abelian groups of order $8$, it is clear this cannot happen.
